# sql server query to return a value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Below is my query which is updating a record in the User table , I want the query to return the UserId which was updated, How can I do this?

```
         UPDATE USER
            SET GroupID = @New_GroupID
           FROM USER 
LEFT OUTER JOIN DOCUMENTS ON User.UserID = Documents.UserID
          WHERE (Documents.UNC = @UNC) 
            AND (User.GroupID = @Old_GroupID)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Scratch previous answer - I read INSERT rather than UPDATE]

Is your query always going to update a single row only?

```
Declare @ID int

SELECT @ID=User.UserID
FROM User 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Documents ON User.UserID = Documents.UserID
WHERE     (Documents.UNC = @UNC) AND (User.GroupID = @Old_GroupID)

UPDATE User
Set GroupID = @New_GroupID
Where UserID = @ID

If @@RowCount = 1
 Return @ID
Else
 Return -1  /* problem - multiple rows updated */
```

Comment: +1: Dunno what version of SQL Server, valid question about how many values can be expected to return.

Answer (score 4):

For SQL Server 2005+, you can use the [OUTPUT clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx):

```
UPDATE USER
   SET GroupID = @New_GroupID
OUTPUT INSERTED.id AS ID
     FROM USER u
LEFT JOIN DOCUMENTS d ON d.userid = u.userid
    WHERE d.UNC = @UNC 
      AND u.GroupID = @Old_GroupID
```

Comment: (+1) Never come across OUTPUT clause... been working in SQL2005/SQL2008 for long enough, but obviously still locked in SQL2000 thinking!

Comment: @CJM: I'm unfamiliar with the OUTPUT clause too - so far, I like Oracle's equivalent, the `RETURNING` clause a little more.

Answer (score 0):

If UserId is your Identity colum, add `Select @@Scope_Identity` after your the current update statement.

If not, you only need a little modification:

```
Update User
Set GroupID = @New_GroupID
FROM  User LEFT OUTER JOIN
      Documents ON User.UserId = Documents.UserID
WHERE Documents.UNC = @UNC AND User.GroupID = @Old_GroupID

Select UserId from User where [YourIdentityColumn] = @@Scope_Identity
```

Comment: Does @@Identity only return the Identity of the last row INSERTed?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187342.aspx

Comment: [@@SCOPE_IDENTITY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx) is a better choice

Comment: This is an UPDATE query - AFAIK Scope_Identity() and @@Identity only work on INSERTS.

Comment: OMG Ponies (and everyone else) is correct.  My brain farted and I went to @@Identity instead of @@SCOPE_Identity.  Edit Forthcoming.